# Error in image.visualize: Creating NDWI animation series for Landsat 8

Tags: qgis, python, google-earth-engine, animation, normalized-difference-water-index

I'm currently working on QGIS with GEE plugin, making NDWI animation series for Landsat 8. Im getting a error in image.visualize: `Expected a string or list of strings for field 'bands'...` at the end of the script. I would some advises how to solve this or how to end the script and get the animation link in GEE.

```
L8_comp_1 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1').filterDate('2013-02-01', '2014-12-01').select(['B3','B5']).sort('system:time_start').filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',Cloud_cover))

def function(img):
  doy = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).getRelative('day', 'year')
  return img.set('doy', doy)

col = L8_comp_1.map(function)
distinctDOY = col.filterDate('2013-01-01', '2014-01-01')
filter = ee.Filter.equals(leftField = 'doy', rightField = 'doy')
join = ee.Join.saveAll('doy_matches')
joincol = ee.ImageCollection(join.apply(distinctDOY, col, filter))

def addNDWI(img):
    NDWI = img.normalizedDifference(['B3','B5']).rename('NDWI').copyProperties(img,['bands'])
    return img.addBands(NDWI)

withNDWI = joincol.map(addNDWI).select('NDWI')

def function2(img):
    doycol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(img.get('doy_matches'))
    return doycol.reduce(ee.Reducer.median())

comp = withNDWI.map(function2)

def function3(img):
  return img.visualize({'min': 0.5,'max': 1,'palette': ['00FFFF', '0000FF']})

rgbVis = comp.map(function3)

gifParams = {
  'region': region,
  'dimensions': 600,
  'crs': 'EPSG:3857',
  'framesPerSecond': 10
}
print(rgbVis.getVideoThumbURL(gifParams))
```

Answer (score 3):

The Earth Engine API follows the style of the host language, at least in the following manner: while in JavaScript, you can pass arguments by name using `{...}`, when writing Python you must use Python's built-in *named arguments,* not a dictionary.

The specific error you received happened because without a name given, the argument is taken as the *first* parameter of `visualize`, which is `bands`, which requires a list rather than a dictionary.

To function as you intended, replace

```py
  return img.visualize({'min': 0.5,'max': 1,'palette': ['00FFFF', '0000FF']})
```

with

```py
  return img.visualize(min=0.5, max=1, palette=['00FFFF', '0000FF'])
```

Disclaimer: I have not run this code or examined it for further errors.